# Why I can't install a specific version of MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I want install mongoDB 2.6.6, i follow this tutorial (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/)

```
daniela.morais@tusk:/var/lib$ sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.6.6 mongodb-org-server=2.6.6 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.6 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.6 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '2.6.6' for 'mongodb-org' was not found
E: Version '2.6.6' for 'mongodb-org-server' was not found
E: Version '2.6.6' for 'mongodb-org-shell' was not found
E: Version '2.6.6' for 'mongodb-org-mongos' was not found
E: Version '2.6.6' for 'mongodb-org-tools' was not found
```

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb there is a few more steps behind your tried cmd take a look at the link.

Comment: @Fresher I followed the steps but still the error occurs

Comment: Because the repository location was changed as it actually says on the referenced manual page. If you changed the version for the documentation then you would have got this: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ which shows the correct repository location and setup for that version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To install mongodb 2.6 you'll need to follow this tutorial: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu

After adding the public key,

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10
```

the differentiating step is adding this source:

```
echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Then you can install 2.6 with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

When I ran this installation on Ubuntu I get 2.6.8. You can check by using

```
mongod --version
```

Answer (score 1):

If you enter `apt-cache show <pkgname>` it will give you a list of versions that are available form your package repository.

Try: `apt-cache show mongodb-org`.

If you enter `apt-cache show mongodb-org | grep Version` it will show you *only* the version numbers.

If you get "E: No packages found", you need to create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list` as described on the page you linked first, then run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: The mongodb-3.0.list file is not going to help with MongoDB 2.6.6 installation. The manual page is very clear why.